# where is Docker options in command line?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, command, docker-machine

when i learn Docker

```
root@vultr:/# docker

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default "/root/.docker")
  -c, --context string     Name of the context to use to connect to the daemon (overrides DOCKER_HOST env var and default context set with "docker context use")
  -D, --debug              Enable debug mode
  -H, --host list          Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -l, --log-level string   Set the logging level ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal") (default "info")
      --tls                Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
      --tlscacert string   Trust certs signed only by this CA (default "/root/.docker/ca.pem")
      --tlscert string     Path to TLS certificate file (default "/root/.docker/cert.pem")
      --tlskey string      Path to TLS key file (default "/root/.docker/key.pem")
      --tlsverify          Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version            Print version information and quit
```

Options are listed
but
A classic command is that

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/sh
```

-i :Interactive

-t ：terminal

I can't find options ，where it is ?

I can find it ,if i have same question in the future

Comment: The options are shown in the output you've posted...

Comment: Each sub-command has its own help text,I think that is my wanted question ,thanks about your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each sub-command has its own help text:

```
$ docker run --help                                                                                      
                                                                                                         
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
                                                                                                         
Run a command in a new container

Options:                                            
      --add-host list                  Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip)
  -a, --attach list                    Attach to STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR
      --blkio-weight uint16            Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000, or 0 to
                                       disable (default 0)
      --blkio-weight-device list       Block IO weight (relative device weight) (default [])
      --cap-add list                   Add Linux capabilities
      --cap-drop list                  Drop Linux capabilities
      --cgroup-parent string           Optional parent cgroup for the container
...
```

Comment: thanks,it is that